# CodeFirst:The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I create a Test Project to test my queries , every thing goes okay except when i try to test a method which use `Entity Connection` ,I get the following exception :

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

---

[image]

---

My connection string in `app.config` in the `TestQuery` Project which is my startup project is:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataLayer.Context" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestQ;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

---

All the methods which use linq to entity works just fine and brings the data except this one ?

Comment: `.` is not a valid value for `Data Source`?

Comment: @masa :this's my local db !!

Comment: Please copy & paste code instead of an image.

Comment: I happen to see now that you offered a bounty. But in the mean time it hasn't become any more clear to me what else I can do for you. You're *clearly* executing an Entity SQL command. I showed you a better way to do it, because an Entity Command doesn't accept the standard connection string you feed to It, only an entity connection string (containing metadata), that you get for free when you use `objectContext.CreateQuery`. You're NOT executing native SQL. And an Entity Command *can't execute native SQL*.

Answer (score 5):

This is not the way to execute an Entity SQL command. You should do this instead:

```
// If you have a DbContext instance:
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
var query = objectContext.CreateQuery<Crop>(eSQL);
var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,The exception in the connection initiation ,not in the query it self .Could you take a look at the connection string please ?

Comment: This works for me but thisn't what i were asking about, i ask about `run native sql with entity framework` like `ADO.net` ,i want in this case to talk with sql client directly , i search over the internet and i find this method but i get the above exception

Comment: But what you've got here is an [`EntityCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entitycommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), by which you can only run Entity SQL, no native SQL. I think the named connection only provides a regular connection string, not en entity connection string (containing metadata). You should run raw SQL by `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery` or `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`.

Comment: yeah you are right i use `entity sql` with `entity command` but i get an exception in the connection string itself

Comment: I know. The problem is that your connection string is not an entity connection string. You have to build an entity connection string containing metadata. But it's much easier to run E-SQL as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename you connection name, in instance to this: "TestConn"

```
using(var con = new EntityConnection("name=TestConn"))
```

Another thing to try is to obtain you connection string from app.config and then to pass it in the constructor of EntityConnection.

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConn"].ConnectionString
var eConnection = new EntityConnection(cs);
```